# Find Cloudwatch log group for a given resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm creating a logs aggregator lambda to send Cloudwatch logs to a private log analysis service. Given the number of resources used by my employer, it was decided to create a *subscription* lambda that handles log group subscription to the aggregator.

The solution works fine, but it requires to manually search a resource's log group via amazon console and then invoke the subscription lambda with it.

My question:

Is there a way to, given a resource arn, find which log group is mapped to it? Since I'm using Cloudformation to create resources it is easy to export a resource's arn.

**UPDATE**

To present an example:

Let's say I have the following arn:

`arn:aws:appsync:<REGION>:<ACCOUNTID>apis/z3pihpr4gfbzhflthkyjjh6yvu`

which is an Appsync GraphQL API.

What I want it a method (using te API or some automated solution) to get the Cloudwatch log group of that resource.

Comment: You say `given a resource arn`. What type of resource? Give an example: input, expected output etc.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [describe-log-groups](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+cli+describe-log-groups&oq=aws+cli+describe-log&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.7161j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) command. It is available on the cli, must also be there on the API.
To get the names of the log groups you can go with:

```
aws logs describe-log-groups --query 'logGroups[*].logGroupName' --log-group-name-prefix '/aws/appsync/[name-of-the-resource]'
```

Output will look like this:

> [
>      "/aws/appsync/[name-of-your-resource]"
>   ]

Comment: Not quite what I was looking at the time but a pretty good solution